# Group by array or shared value

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports, grouping

My invoice report pull due dates depending on the selection of Payment Plan Code on UI (either semi, monthly, quarterly, annually, or even 18 installments.) It also accordingly pulls gross premium per due date. I need to pull this table per due date and the sum of the gross premium if they fall into one due date.

What I do is break and save the due dates into array. How can I group by them? Crystal doesn't seem to allow me to group by a shared value, or group by array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need array for this purpose.. using array complicates the report instead you can manipulate grouping like below:

Create a formula like below and use this formula to group.

```
if parameterselection = "monthly"
then Month(duedate)
else if parameterselection = "yearly"
then Year(duedate)

    .
    .
    .
    .
formula till end
```

Edit-------------------------------------------

In this case as per your comment you need to create one more group (Group2) with due date.

Now you have two groups group 1 is the one I wrote first and group2 using due date and this works

Comment: Thank you very much for the input!  :) Though my requirement is like, for monthly, there will be 12 different due dates, for 18 installments, there are 18 different due dates and so on... Array is the only way I can think about for now to keep all these dates. But I will definitely try on this. Thank you!

Comment: Still for this requirement there is no need of array... I have edited the answer check and let me know